# Not catching SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have dropdownlist in a GridView (Actually have a bunch) but I am only concerned about one of them.  I need to capture when the user makes a new selection to see if they want to add a item into the dropdownlist.  Here is my code ..

This never gets called:

```
 protected void DebtorDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex];
    DropDownList list = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DebtorDropDownList");
    string temp = list.SelectedValue;
 }
```

Here is the ASP code:

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DebtorDropDownList" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server"
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="FirstName" DataValueField="contactkey" 
                        SelectedIndexChanged="DebtorDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" >
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Select</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem >Add New Contact</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AuditDevConnectionString2 %>" 
                        SelectCommand="sp_fc_vm_getSpokeTo" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" DefaultValue="0" Name="DebtorKey" 
                                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </ItemTemplate>
```

What am I missing?  Also am using the right code to find the correct control?

Comment: Did you specify `runat="server"` for the whole `<form>`?

Comment: i guess on your postback, your dropdownlist is rebinding. Why don't you catch that value in Gridview itemCommand? Move your sqldatasource out of griview

Comment: I found my problem.  If you look at my ASP closely you will notice that the "SelectedIndexChanged" event is missing "On".  Once I added that things worked as expected.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized. Neither the question nor the answer is likely to help anyone else out. It is suggested that the author delete both the answer and the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem.  If you look at my ASP closely you will notice that the "SelectedIndexChanged" event is missing "on"

Comment: dont forget to flag your answer :)